# Cordova File Plugin and Angular - Read JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, cordova, ionic-framework

I try to make a user service with connect with Facebook. I've try LocalStorage plugin, but when memory is low, iOS delete files and cause white screen.

So, now, I use Cordova File Plugin and I want implement this User service for store some user datas.

This is my first app, my target is iOS and Android, My device is iPhone 5s, iOS 8.3 and I develop in MacOS.

In Config.xml, I've do this :

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library"/>
```

And, my user service is like that :

```
myapp.service('UserService', function($cordovaFile) {

  var setUser = function(user_data) {
    $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "myapp_user", JSON.stringify(json), true)
  }

  var userIsLoggedIn = function() {
    var user = getUser()
    return user && user.authResponse && user.authResponse.userID != null;
  }

  var userIsNotLoggedIn = function() {
    var user = getUser()
    return user && user.authResponse && user.authResponse.userID == null;
  }

  var getUser = function() {
    return $cordovaFile.readAsText("myapp_user");
  }

  return {
    getUser: getUser,
    setUser: setUser,
    userIsLoggedIn: userIsLoggedIn,
    userIsNotLoggedIn: userIsNotLoggedIn
  }

})
```

In facebook connect, I've do this for recover data (It's work with LocalStorage, the problem is not here)

```
    UserService.setUser({
      authResponse: authResponse,
      name: profileInfo.name,
      user_id: profileInfo.id,
      first_name: profileInfo.first_name,
      picture: profileInfo.picture.data.url,
      ionic_id: ionicUser.id
    })
```

So, the login Facebook work like a charm, but when I want to read JSON data, I can't !
I have a white screen and error : UserID is not defined !

Can you help me to read JSON file ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**.Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? What is your target platform and their target versions? Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Are you developing on Windows or MacOS? Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: Done, If you need more information I stand here. :)

Comment: Okay thanks for information. I do not know Angular. I assume you did injection correctly. I think the issue is `getUser()`. Also, can you show the JSON? I have links to [online tools](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/free-online-resources.md). See: **JSON Viewers**

Comment: This is the problem, first I have no idea if JSON is created, and second I want to know if readAsText work really with JSON ... 
Before, with localStorage I use : JSON.parse(localStorage.get("myapp_user")  || '{}') and it's work ... Have you a snippet idea for resolve this ? (I can put my localStorage service if you want)

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't know how Angular works with the file plugin. I have a working example, but it is not that simple. The file plugin is confusing and it took me more than a week to figure it out. It works with *Phonegap Build*, a cloud-based service by Adobe/Phonegap. You are welcome to look at it: [cordova-storage-file](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/cordova-storage-file).